# Auto populate menu with posts in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Well, I've been searching for a while on how to do this with no luck. Maybe it's simple, maybe I don't know what keywords to use to find the solution, but I'd be really grateful if someone could help me out.

What I want is very simple (I think?): A menu item that gets automatically populated with posts from a certain or all categories. The only similar thing I found was a plugin called "Custom Post Types Auto Menu", but as its title suggests, it only works on custom created post types and that doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need this shortcode: [display-posts]

If you put that in your page it will automatically load all the posts in there

more info on:
https://en.support.wordpress.com/display-posts-shortcode/

Comment: I don't think shorcodes work inside menus and that's what I'm after.